# How can I import a component from GitHub repository

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, cometchat

##### what I have done so far

step 1. yarn add githubURL

step 2.
"comet-chat-repo": "https://github.com/Vivek/cometChatRepo.git",

above file added in package.json

step 3. Trying to import the components from the GitHub repo

import { CometChatGroupListWithMessages } from 'comet-chat-repo';

> Module not found: Can't resolve 'comet-chat-repo' in 'C:\Users

Comment: try this -- > npm install --save your_repo_url/master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
npm install git://github.com/username/repo.git#branch-name

yarn add git://github.com/username/repo.git#branch-name

// Example
yarn add git://github.com/denvash/react-pagination-example.git#master
```

Then import it according to the repo path, for example:

```
import Pagination from 'react-pagination/src/components/Pagination.react'
```

Comment: tried but still got the error
Module not found: Can't resolve 'cometChatRepo/cometchat-pro-react-ui-kit/CometChatWorkspace/src/components/Groups

Comment: my components are in sub-folder not in root folder so i tried 

yarn add "url/<sub-folder>"

and it works